# Executing executable file by means of script file

Tags: unix, script

For executing file in linux terminal we run something like this:
./sflm -start
Now, if i want this procedure is done by executing a script file what should i do ? I want to for example run this command :
./script.pl
and then it run automatically my main command (./sflm -start).
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Do you want a shell script to execute a series of executables?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that, from your question, you would like to run a specific command from a script.

Quite simply, in your script, start with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and below that, add your command name

```
sflm
```

Of course, this assumes that you have moved the `sflm` binary to a /.../bin folder. If you haven't, then

```
bash /path/to/sflm
```

This specifies that `/path/to/sflm` is to be run by `bash`. Substitute `bash` with any other shell of your choice.

Finally,

```
chmod 775 /path/to/script
```

And `./script` to run.